# How to read row data when insert is submit in SQL command?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I wrote this code for insert a row into the table:

```
SqlConnection TITLEconnection = new SqlConnection(conn);
SqlCommand prikaz = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Customer_Care_Database_Analysis_TITLE(sharhe_amaliyat,az_tarix,ta_tarix,code_faaliyat,name_faaliyat) values(@sharhe_amaliyat,@az_tarix,@ta_tarix,@code_faaliyat,@name_faaliyat)",TITLEconnection);
prikaz.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sharhe_amaliyat", sharhe_amaliyat);
prikaz.Parameters.AddWithValue("@az_tarix", az_tarix);
prikaz.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ta_tarix", ta_tarix);
//prikaz.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ta_tarix", ta_tarix);
prikaz.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code_faaliyat", code_faaliyat);
prikaz.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name_faaliyat", name_faaliyat);
TITLEconnection.Open();
prikaz.ExecuteNonQuery();
TITLEconnection.Close();
```

But I want to insert up row, and then read inserted column. For example insert "A" character to `code_faaliyat` column, and after that read `code_faaliyat` character "A", How can I solve that?

Comment: Do you want to read recently inserted value in code_faaliyat column?? you already have it as a parameter passed into your method. am i missing something?

Comment: Yes my friend , i want read recently inserted value.

Comment: Do you have auto identity column on the table?

Comment: @DarkKnight no i dont have identity field.

Comment: what is the primary key on the table?

Comment: @DarkKnight i dont have any primary key on table,that table is temp table,and dont necessary primary key.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85486/discussion-between-dark-knight-and-behzad-razzaqi).

Answer (score 1):

Change the insert statement and then use:

```
Int32 newId = (Int32) myCommand.ExecuteScalar();
```

Try this:

```
string insertSql = 
    "INSERT INTO Customer_Care_Database_Analysis_TITLE(sharhe_amaliyat,az_tarix,ta_tarix,code_faaliyat,name_faaliyat) OUTPUT INSERTED.ID VALUES(@sharhe_amaliyat,@az_tarix,@ta_tarix,@code_faaliyat,@name_faaliyat)";

using (SqlConnection TITLEconnection = new SqlConnection(conn)))
{
   SqlCommand prikaz = new SqlCommand(insertSql, TITLEconnection);

    rikaz.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sharhe_amaliyat", sharhe_amaliyat);
    prikaz.Parameters.AddWithValue("@az_tarix", az_tarix);
    prikaz.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ta_tarix", ta_tarix);
    prikaz.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ta_tarix", ta_tarix);
    prikaz.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code_faaliyat", code_faaliyat);
    prikaz.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name_faaliyat", name_faaliyat);

    TITLEconnection.Open();
    prikaz.ExecuteNonQuery();

    Int32 newId = (Int32) prikaz.ExecuteScalar();

    TITLEconnection.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're utilizing `ExecuteNonQuery()` to submit, you're only going to receive the number of rows that got inserted.

Rather, you should look into using [ExecuteScalar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) to have it return the identity value of the inserted row, then perform a select statement within an [ExecuteReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k(v=vs.110).aspx) to read the inserted data. I'd recommend looking at the examples at the above-linked pages for the use of using and try/catch blocks around your code as a better practice as well.

Comment: It's a link directly to the MSDN documentation for either command. Additionally, it's not clear from the original question what the primary key would be, so I can't easily provide an example of the ExecuteReader command.

Comment: error:Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score -3):

I wrote this code:

```
SqlConnection TITLEconnection = new SqlConnection(conn);
    SqlCommand prikaz = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Customer_Care_Database_Analysis_TITLE(sharhe_amaliyat,az_tarix,ta_tarix,code_faaliyat,name_faaliyat) values(@sharhe_amaliyat,@az_tarix,@ta_tarix,@code_faaliyat,@name_faaliyat);SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS bigint)", TITLEconnection);
    prikaz.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sharhe_amaliyat", sharhe_amaliyat);
    prikaz.Parameters.AddWithValue("@az_tarix", az_tarix);
    prikaz.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ta_tarix", ta_tarix);
    prikaz.Parameters.AddWithValue("@code_faaliyat", code_faaliyat);
    prikaz.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name_faaliyat", name_faaliyat);
    TITLEconnection.Open();

    id = (Int64)prikaz.ExecuteScalar();

    TITLEconnection.Close();
```

and it works.